# How to Convince management to upgrade to .Net 4.0

Tags: .net

We developed an application using .net 2.0.
We license our software which means whenever we release a new version, we have to push out the change to all our existing clients.

No one in my group has the slightest motivation to upgrade to a newer version of .net. They simple see it as more work for our support team to deploy and argue that clients will be resistant to any change.

Can anyone point me in the direction of some argument i could present to Non programmers that might sway them.

If noting else, some argument that it is safe, and will not cause our clients any harm who already have the .net 2.0 framework on their machines?

I figure it's hopeless. I'm gonna be stuck using the .net 2.0 framework until for another 4 or 5 years i bet... perhaps longer :( help!

I really want to be able to use WCF, LINQ, WPF (possible), and the option to use the Entity Framework 4.0.!

thanks

jonathan

Comment: You can use linq-to-objects with .net 2. You just need a C# 3 compiler and a third party implementation of the `Enumerable` class.

Comment: Interesting how many people seem to think i should not push for new technology use... i'll have to think on that. However, that is not what i asked :) I know that being able to leverage WCF and EntityFramework 4.0 will have many long term benefits, but i find it very hard to explain it to management.

Comment: Yes. That's interesting. Quite often we don't get an answer to what we've asked for. But with so many non-answers you ask yourself if the question was wrong rather than answers! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to agree with @Lior Kogan, in that upgrading for the sake of it is not something that you should be arguing with management about.

In fact, there are good arguments for *not* upgrading:

- if you've got a stable platform, why introduce potential instability?
- if we upgrade this, will it force us to spend more money upgrading other things?
- will it mean we have to force our customers to upgrade as well?

All these things are big negatives to a business, and make a good case for maintaining the status-quo.

However, upgrades are necessary at some point. There are a lot of very frustrated web developers out there who are cursing businesses worldwide for taking the above aproach to Internet Explorer v6: While those businesses were arguably doing the right thing for some time, they've now passed the point where it is difficult to defend staying still. It may not be the case for you now, but eventually the same will hold true for a .NET upgrade.

The argument here would be that the old version of the technology is obsolete:

- it is no longer supported by the vendor, particularly with security fixes.
- it is no longer sold by the vendor, making it hard to increase your number of users.
- other technologies that we use rely on the newer version.
- our customers are asking us for features that can only be delivered using the new version.

If any one of those points holds true than you may have a good argument for an upgrade that will win over the management. If not, you may have to stick it out.

Answer (score 9):

In my experience a business that doesn't keep its technology stack up-to-date loses their best developers, leaving the business with poor systems and service. Which certainly affects bottom-line.

Non-technical managers often find that difficult to grasp or understand, and are more pressured with short-term concerns.

Therefore, you'll have to emphasise the financial benefits of upgrading.

Look at how Entity-Framework, to take one example, will save time (money) writing data access code. Work out the difference between manually coding your data access layer and auto-generating code with EF. Present the cost-saving to management responsible for budgets.

If that fails and you're surrounded by people who lack any motivation to use new technology, and you really like new technology, you may need to find a more suitable job.

Answer (score 8):

So your real motivation is

"I really want to be able to use WCF, LINQ, WPF (possible), and the option to use the Entity Framework 4.0.!"

This is not a good enough reason for upgrading! If you can't convince yourself that the company is going to get more profits, don't try to convince the management.

Sometimes there is no reason to upgrade, and it may be even a wrong business move. Consider your business case if you want to convince managers.

Comment: +1 because its so true. I switched to 4.0 shortly after it came out (okay, maybe the day) and love it, but I'm mostly a one-man shop. I didn't upgrade existing clients, new ones just were done with 4.0. I would recommend that ask your management to let you use 4.0 with any new projects that aren't directly related to your 2.0. Maybe with the next major release of your 2.0 product you can make the switch.

Comment: So you think it's reasonable for a group of developers to keep using the same technology for 10 years? I see little risk in doing the upgrade, and thought the long term benefits warranted it... blah.

Comment: Hehe... this was the 2.0 release of our product. When i got hired, we started doing a rewrite from the existing codebase that was all writtine in vb6 (almost 6 years ago).

Comment: @jonchicoine: It's reasonable on the part of a business to keep using the same technology for 40 or 50 years.  There are still businesses run on Cobol.

Comment: @Jon - The fact you don't understand the risk might be the reason you cannot talk mangement into using .NET 4.0.  If something works why change it?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to push this change I would simply approach it in another way.  If you are currently using Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2008 you can target the project for a specfic platform.

In a future planned update suggest the target version of the framework be changed.  Modify your requirements to require 3.5 and/or 4.0 and release the upgrade.  Everything will work exactly the same, you can also easily include the .NET Framework installer itself, depending on how you release updates.

Once you get the software to a newer version you can start to work on proposed changes.  Of course your reasons are still not valid.  You won't be able to use WPF for instance based on the fact it sounds like a WinForms application.  Unless you have a need for Linq I am not sure the reason you want to use it.

Of course you could also do your proposed changes on the side I suppose, entirely depends on how you are assigned work, might involve doing it after your 8 hours each day or on the weekends.

Comment: There is rarely a hard need for linq, but it's a nice to have feature very often. But since it mainly consists of language features(extension-methods and lamdas) you can use it with VS2008 even when targeting .net 2 if you use a third party implementation.

Comment: I work from home... and am currently spending 20 or 30 hours per week studying newer technologies, so in 2014 my knowledge base isn't still based on .net 2.0. ... And yes, that is really all i want, update to VS 2010, continue to target 2.0 for our current stuff if need be, but get my tech team to also install .net 4.0 so new (small utility apps and such) could possible take advantage of newer technologies... blah

Comment: @Jon - You still have not given a valid reason to upgrade.  If you know .NET 2.0 then you know .NET 4.0 I can speak for experience.  WPF is a different beast and is not included in this statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should find out how many of your existing clients have the .NET 4 framework installed. This will quantify the upgrade task you and your support team face. If you have 50 end users then perhaps half of them will have the newer framework already (i found this to be the case).
If you have 5,000 end users well then your task is larger.

As for arguments to convince management:
1) You need to keep up with the latest technologies (to some degree) to attract and maintain staff.
2) The technology offers new ways to test and debug code (eg code dumps, parallel stacks)
3) You can use that library that you really need that is only available in .NET>2.0
4) you don't want to be forced to migrate/upgrade - best to do it when it suits the company rather than when all the COBOL programmers have died.

*disclaiimer* I don't necessarily believe each of these is valid 100% of the time but they can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Think software development as a business like any other business. No factory changes its perfectly running machines just because a new model of that machine has 10 more buttons to perform 10 new actions which are not required by that factory.
Software houses are there to generate profit not to educate developer; University will be a better place for education.

Comment: I am educating myself, and would like the company to benefit from my knowledge. WCF and the Entity Framework 4.0 are how i would like to expose our business objects... I see lot of areas where have the option of knew technology would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix : Just list the bugs and lack of features in Entity Framework 1.0 and the almost crappy edmx editor.
Long Term Fix: Adhere to Hollywood principle and management will call u when they are ready for .net 4